# Erro ao implementar Room Persistence Library + Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Ao tentar rodar uma aplicação desenvolvida em Kotlin com o ROOM Persistence Library tenho o seguinte retorno:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for br.com.androidxexample.Database.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

O erro ocorre ao tentar executar o databaseBuilder

```
val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
   applicationContext,
   AppDatabase::class.java, "localDB"
).build()
```

**build.gradle (Module:App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.androidxexample"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha06"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

GITHUB do Projeto: https://github.com/tpoderoso/AndroidXExample

Comment: Adicione na pergunta as dependências do seu projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Room gera em tempo de compilação algumas classes para seu funcionamento:

- Uma classe que extenderá a classe abstrata que você anotou com `@Database`
- Classes classes que implementam / extendem as interfaces / classes que você anotar com `@Dao`

A biblioteca responsável por isso é a `androidx.room:room-compiler`. Seu funcionamento depende de um [processador de anotação](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-annotation-processing-tutorial-part-1-a-practical-approach).

Normalmente você adicionaria esta dependência com a função `annotationProcessor`. Mas, como você está usando o Kotlin, ele tem um plugin pra compilador próprio para isso chamado `kapt`.

Seu build.gradle deve importar o plugin `kotlin-kapt` e importar a dependência com o `kapt`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

...
...

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    ...
}
```